# Are ridge and LASSO shrinkage parameters functions of the number of features?

Tags: regression, regularization

I was wondering if Ridge and LASSO shrinkage parameters (I am referring to the lambda in the canonical loss function) are functions of the number of features if one is targeting a "constant" shrinkage level?

An example is: let's suppose I determine my optimal shrinkage parameter to be some number x for a set of 4 features that are appropriately standardized. If I then bring a 5th feature into my feature set (also appropriately standardized), would I need to revise my previously selected shrinkage parameter if I wanted to target the same level of total shrinkage as before? Does the answer differ for Ridge vs. LASSO?

Answer (score 2):

To ground the discussion I will consider a problem with $n$ points and $p$ parameters. Furthermore I will assume that the data matrix $\boldsymbol{X}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times{p}}$ has been [whitened](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95806/how-to-whiten-the-data-using-principal-component-analysis), such that $\boldsymbol{X}^T\boldsymbol{X}=n\boldsymbol{I}_{p\times{p}}$.

Then the question relates to a regularized [M-estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-estimator) problem with objective function of type
$$E[\boldsymbol{c}]=\tfrac{1}{k}\|\boldsymbol{Xc}-\boldsymbol{y}\|_k^k+\tfrac{\lambda}{j}\|\boldsymbol{c}\|_j^j$$
for some regularization strength $\lambda\geq{0}$ and data/penalty norms $k,j\in\mathbb{N}$, and seeks a solution $\boldsymbol{c}\in\mathbb{R}^p$.

In the case of [ridge regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/ridge-regression/info) ($k=j=2$) we have the solution
$$(n+\lambda)\boldsymbol{c}=\boldsymbol{X}^T\boldsymbol{y}$$

From this, we can see that the magnitude of a coefficient $c_i$ will be impacted by $\lambda/n$, the relative magnitude of the penalty vs. the number of data points.

In terms of $p$, the answer depends on what "shrinkage level" means. From the above solution, the magnitude of $|c_i|$ is not impacted by $p$, but the norm $\|\boldsymbol{c}\|$ may scale with $p$.

However commonly "shrinkage" is not really of direct interest per se. Instead,  the goal of the regularization is to prevent [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting), in which case  [generalization error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalization_error) is more relevant. In this context, it would be more appropriate to set the value of $\lambda$ based on something like cross-validation. Then the general expectation would be that the optimal $\lambda$ would tend to increase with $p$.

I believe these same considerations should apply to the general problem, regardless of the values of $k$ and $j$ (i.e. also for LASSO, where $k=2$, $j=1$).

Comment: I keep thinking that this question is more complicated than it sounds.  My thought experiment is suppose the p variables $X_1, \ldots X_p $ explain 10% of the variance of the response variable Y.  One then adds another variable  which explain 89% of the variance of Y and is orthogonal to all the others.  Or suppose that $X_{p+1} = Y +Z$ where Z is pure noise.  I can't believe that the optimal strategy is to do anything but associate almost, if not all of the 'lambda' to this new variable.  In this last case,

Comment: I'm almost positive that the lasso would assign all the first p variable the value of 0.  There are formulas in 'Elements of Statistical Learning' that explain for a given value of lambda what happens to the coefficients of the regularized regression.  The stickler from my point of view for turning this into an answer rather than a comment is, "what is the meaning of the word optimal".

Comment: A recent free reference for LASSO is [Hastie, Tibshirani, WainWright 2015](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/StatLearnSparsity/). For my problem above, this gives the LASSO solution as $c=\mathrm{sgn}[\hat{c}]\big(\hat{c}-\frac{\lambda}{n}\big)_+$, where $\hat{c}=\frac{X^Ty}{n}$ is the OLS solution.

Comment: The same solution is in my reference too- as well as the formula for ridge.  There are two points.  How does $\hat{c} $ change when a new variable is added and how does the optimal $\lambda $ change with new variables.  That is what seems very hard to me in general.